# node-jq how to solve: Could not resolve "child_process"

Tags: node.js, cypress, node-modules, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to use node-js ["npm package"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jq).
I am using it for manipulation with jsons during cypress tests. I was using jq-web since cypress 9, but after migration to cypress 10 i would like to try something new.

When i start my tests i get error:

```
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/node-jq/lib/exec.js:6:51: ERROR: Could not resolve "child_process"
```

I was trying to add into my package.json this line:

```
"browser":{ "child_process": false }
```

but it didn´t help.

Can you help or provide me some information how to solve it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used lodash instead of jq.